VibrationalStructureProblem in Qiskit with PySCF
I am looking for some example code that solves the Vibrational Structure Problem in Qiskit using PySCF driver (not Gaussian) using a recent version of Qiskit (1.2 or 1.3), preferably with UCCSD ansatz.
